# Convert sql query with nested sum to linq2sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to convert this SQL into a Linq2SQL query, however, I'm at the point of just dragging a stored procedure into the dbml and hoped someone could do a better job.  When there are no records for the nested query, it is returning null.

SQL:

```
SELECT
    Table1.Field1 -
    ISNULL(
            (
            SELECT  
                SUM(Table2.Field1) 
            FROM Table2 
                INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.ID = Table3.Table2ID 
            WHERE Table3.Table1ID = Table1.ID
            )
            ,0)
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    (Table1.ID = @ID)
```

Linq2SQL

```
     return (from q in db.Table1s
                    where q.ID == id
                    select q.Field1.GetValueOrDefault() - 
                            (from o in db.Table2s 
                             join r in db.Table3s on o.ID equals r.Table2ID.GetValueOrDefault(0)
                             where r.Table1ID == q.ID
                             select Convert.ToInt32(o.Field1.GetValueOrDefault(0))).Sum()
                    ).SingleOrDefault()
```

Can anyone do a better job.

Comment: why are you unsatisfied with your posted Linq2SQL? Does it not work as desired, or is it just too convoluted/ugly?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.  I can't get the isnull round the sum to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concise version using method syntax and lambda expressions:

```
from t1 in Table1s
select t1.Field1 -  Table3s.Where(x=>x.Table1ID == t1.ID).Sum(y=>y.Table2.Field1)
```

A more readable version using query syntax with a let statement:

```
from t1 in Table1s
let tmp = 
(
    from t3 in Table3s
    where t3.Table1ID == t1.ID
    select t3.Table2.Field1
).Sum()
select t1.Field1 -  tmp
```

I strongly recommend using a tool like [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to design your queries, because it will show you the SQL that is generated. This allows you to tune your more expensive queries for better results.

Its also useful for quick prototyping and testing of short blocks of code.

Comment: +1.  I do use linqpad but was trying to do this in a hurry and getting  nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:
I would formulate the sql in another way. Like this:

```
SELECT
    Table1.Field1 - ISNULL(tblTemp.SumOfField1,0)
FROM
    Table1
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  
                SUM(Table2.Field1) AS SumOfField1,
                Table3.Table1ID
            FROM Table2 
                INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.ID = Table3.Table2ID 
            GROUP BY 
                Table3.Table1ID
        ) AS tblTemp
        ON tblTemp.Table1ID = Table1.ID
WHERE
    Table1.ID = @ID
```

And then your linq code can be like this (same result just another way of looking at it):

```
var leftJoin=(
                    from Table2 in db.Table2
                    join Table3 in db.Table3
                        on Table2.ID equals Table3.Table2ID 
                    group Table3 by Table3.Table1ID into g
                    select new
                    {
                        Table1ID=g.Key,
                        SumOf= g.Sum (x =>x.Field1 )
                    }
                );
var output=(
        from Table1 in db.Table1
        from g in leftJoin
            .Where (a =>a.Table1ID==Table1.ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            Table1.ID,
            SumOf=(g.SumOf??0)-Table1.Field1
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a bash.  Makes sense now to pull out the nest into a separate query and also use a ??.

Comment: Yes. Because it will execute as on sql statement. That is because the left join is a IQuerable. If you are fine with the answer then you might consider accepting the answer?

Comment: Arion, the sql is fine but the linq needs a little tweak to work.  I will post the final code as an edit.  Thanks again.